# How do I make jQuery not target my readonly textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the below works for every inbox where the input type is text among other elements on my page, how do I ask the function not to target my readonly textboxes?

```
$('#content select, #content input[type="text"], #content textarea').focusin(function(e) {});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.not('input[type="text"][readonly]')` to it:

```
$('#content select, #content input[type="text"], #content textarea').not('input[type="text"][readonly]').focusin(function(e) {});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gmaF9/)** (basic)

Answer (score 2):

It's just like you typed it.

```
.not("[readonly]")
```

`[...]` is the attribute selector, and since you want all inputs that are *not* readonly, select the ones that don't have a readonly attribute.